# Why is Object type instead of Sheet type used for variable declaration in the following VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code gets user back to the old sheet if a `Chart` is activated, and it shows how many data points are included in the `Chart` before getting back. And I wonder why the variable `Sh` is defined as `Object` rather than `Sheet` in the two event-handler procedures. Same for the variable `OldSheet`.

```
Dim OldSheet As Object

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set OldSheet = Sh
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim Msg As String
    If TypeName(Sh) = "Chart" Then
        Msg = "This chart contains "
        Msg = Msg & ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        Msg = Msg & " data points." & vbNewLine
        Msg = Msg & "Click OK to return to " & OldSheet.Name
        MsgBox Msg
        OldSheet.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks lke use of late binding to me. Normally when interacting with different object models, you use references or you use late binding. I would actually find a good article and brush up on this b/c late binding is something fairly useful from time to time. check this link http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/

Comment: It may be sloppy @Wayne, but it's what Excel inserts when you create the event procedure.  I'm wondering if it's a throwback to earlier spreadsheets when `Sh` may not just be a `Sheet`, a `WorkSheet` or a `ChartSheet`, it could've been a macro sheet.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn it's not any more "sloppy" than any standard .net event handler signature - `(object sender, EventArgs e)`; that `object sender` is *exactly* what `Sh As Object` is here.

Comment: This is also fairly standard practice in the COM world.  There is absolutely zero requirement that all of the callable members of a object are declared on its interfaces.  Passing an `IDispatch` (VBA's `Object`) allows the callback function to query the interface for specific members that it wants to call. It would be more like a default .NET event handler signature of `(dynamic sender, EventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Because there is no such thing as a  'Sheet' in Excel.

Notice the event is `SheetActivate`, not `WorksheetActivate` - the concept of a "sheet" encompasses several types that have nothing in common, other than the ability to be "activated". There is no `Sheet` type in the Excel object model - the `Workbook.Sheets` collection contains various types of objects, *including* `Chart` and `Worksheet` objects.

The `Sh` parameter in the `SheetActivate` event *has* to be an `Object`, because there is no common interface between a `Chart` and a `Worksheet`.

So you need do what you did: verify the type of the object instead of assuming you're dealing with a `Chart` or a `Worksheet` object.

Instead of using the `TypeName` function and thus stringly-typed type checks, you should use the `TypeOf` operator instead:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If TypeOf Sh Is Excel.Worksheet Then
        Debug.Print "Worksheet!"
    ElseIf TypeOf Sh Is Excel.Chart Then
        Debug.Print "Chart!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Something else!"
    End If
End Sub
```

The parameter being `Object` allows future versions to *activate* a "sheet" of a type that couldn't be dreamed of at the time the event declaration was written in the `IWorkbookEvents` hidden interface that every `Workbook` object implements.

Comment: Appreciated. I wonder if it makes any difference here to use Variant instead of Object. They seem both "indeterminate" now.

Comment: @Nicholas `Variant` would have worked too (well except you can't use it there yourself because then the signature will mismatch the event interface definition), but `Object` is much more specific - an `Object` can only ever contain an object reference, whereas a `Variant` can be *anything*, from a `String` literal to an `IUnknown` object reference.

Comment: I see, one last question, you consider `TypeOf` better than `TypeName` here, is this due to the fact that `TypeOf`  is faster?

Comment: @Nicholas no, it's because `TypeOf` is making the type check *strongly-typed* - nothing forbids having your own `Worksheet` class module. If `TypeName(Sh)` returns a `"Worksheet"` string literal, how do you know if that's `Excel.Worksheet` or `VBAProject.Worksheet`? You can't. With `TypeOf Sh Is Excel.Worksheet` there is no possible ambiguity (or imagine checking for a `Range` in Excel when you're referencing the Word object library, which *also* has a `Range` type). It's probably a bit faster too, since there's no string creation and comparison involved.

Comment: FWIW, `TypeOf` is *also* faster.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The short version of the answer is that it *has to* be declared as `Object`. The events are being "fired" through a COM source sink, and that returns an `IDispatch` pointer (known in VBA as `Object`) to anything that has a subscribed callback function.  The `ByVal Sh As Object` parameter is passed to the callback function so that the event handler can determine which object was responsible for raising the event. It's declared in the Excel type library on `dispinterface WorkbookEvents` like this:

```
[id(0x00000619), helpcontext(0x0007ad30)]
void SheetActivate([in] IDispatch* Sh);
```

Even without considering the COM plumbing of its implementation, it *has to* be declared as `Object` because the `Sheets` collection holds both `Worksheet` and `Chart` objects, and the event will fire if *either* type of tab is activated.  The two types don't share a common interface, but they do both source the same event.  That means in order to pass the source object to the event handler, it ***has to*** be passed as late bound (`IDispatch`).  The assumption is that the handler will determine what type of object it was passed and take the appropriate action based on the type of the sender.